# how to get text from html element class vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net

I have this element

```html
<div id="cp-0" class="caption-line" data-time="19.5">
   <div class="caption-line-time">0:19</div>
   <div class="caption-line-text">I used to bite my tongue and hold my breath Scared to rock the boat and make a mess</div>             
</div>
```

I want to get

```
0:19
I used to bite my tongue and hold my breath Scared to rock the boat and make a mess
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is the `InnerText` property of an `XmlElement`.

Details and an example program:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**UPDATE:**
You may use [`HtmlElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type as well. It also has [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

You can also access the inner text by casting the `HtmlElement` to one of the unmanaged MSHTML interfaces, e.g. [`IHTMLElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has the [`innerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property.

You have to add `Microsoft HTML Object Library` COM reference to your project.
(The file name is `mshtml.tlb`.)

Here is an example:

```
For Each child As HtmlElement In element.Children

    ' using System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement type
    If (String.Equals(child.TagName, "div") AndAlso
        String.Equals(child.GetAttribute("class"), "caption-line-time")) Then

        Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", child.InnerText)

    End If

    ' using mshtml.IHTMLElement interface
    Dim htmlElement As IHTMLElement = DirectCast(child.DomElement, IHTMLElement)

    If (String.Equals(htmlElement.tagName, "div") AndAlso
        String.Equals(htmlElement.className, "caption-line-time")) Then

        Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", htmlElement.innerText)

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why XML when there are HTML classes?

Comment: Depending from where this HTML markup comes from it may be easier to load/parse HTML document as an XML content. Anyway I updated my answer with `HtmlElement` and `IHTMLElement` types and examples.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all i solve it by this

```
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
             FileOpen(1, SaveFileDialog1.FileName, OpenMode.Output)
           For Each telement As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")
            Dim tElementClass As String = "caption-line-time"
            Dim selementclass As String = "caption-line-text"
            If telement.OuterHtml.Contains(tElementClass) AndAlso telement.OuterHtml.Contains(selementclass) Then
            Dim conStr As String = telement.GetAttribute("innertext")
            PrintLine(1, conStr)

            End If
               Next
   End If


        FileClose(1)

    End If
```